# Rate of convergence of the prime zeta function P(2)

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

For an application in statistical group theory, we need explicit upper and lower bounds that an expert in number theory (I am not one) may know how to prove.

**Question 1:** What are "good" bounds $f_1(x)<\displaystyle\sum_{p>x}\frac{1}{p^2}<f_2(x)$ where $p>x$ is prime?

For our application, sharper bounds than the following $f_1(x),f_2(x)$ are desirable:
$$ \frac{1}{12\left(\frac{x}{\log(x)-4}+1\right)^4}<\sum_{p>x}\frac{1}{p^2}<\frac{1}{x-1}.$$
The lower bound can hold for $x>x_1$ and the upper bound for $x>x_2$ provided $x_1,x_2$ are "small".

**Question 2:**  Is there a function $f(x)$ and *explicit* positive constants $c_1,c_2$ such that
$$c_1f(x)<\sum_{p>x}\frac{1}{p^2}<c_2f(x)?$$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Indeed, this is a type of question that is standard to those in the know (pretty much exactly what MathOverflow is for!). The famous [paper of Rosser and Schoenfeld](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1255631807) contains many estimates for $\pi(x)$, the number of primes up to $x$: for example, their Corollary 1 tells us that
$$
\frac x{\log x} < \pi(x) < 1.25506 \frac x{\log x} \text{ for } x\ge17.
$$
Bounds for your sum (for $x\ge17$ in this case) can then be found using partial summation. For example, for the lower bound,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\sum_{p>x} \frac1{p^2} &= \int_x^\infty \frac1{t^2} \,d\pi(t) \\
&= \frac{\pi(t)}{t^2}\bigg|_x^\infty + \int_x^\infty \pi(t) \frac2{t^3} \,dt \\
&> \frac1{t\log t}\bigg|_x^\infty + \int_x^\infty \frac2{t^2\log t} \, dt \\
&= -\frac1{x\log x} - 2\mathop{\rm li}\bigg( \frac1x \bigg),
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
where $\mathop{\rm li}(t) = \int_0^t dt/\log t$ is the [logarithmic integral function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function). [The second expression on the top line is a Riemann–Stieltjes integral; if you're not familiar with those, one can verify by hand that the sum equals the expression on the second line.) This last expression can be shown to be asymptotic to $1/(x\log x)$ for large $x$.

The calculation of the upper bound is exactly the same except with an extra factor of $1.25506$. Indeed, a more careful calculation (using sharper bounds from Rosser and Schoenfeld from earlier on the same page) will give both upper and lower bounds that are asymptotic to $1/(x\log x)$.

Comment: The last displayed line has sign errors.

Comment: @Glasby Two errors fixed, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

An answer to Question 2 follows from the lemma below by letting $y\to\infty$.

**Lemma.** Suppose $x,y$ are real numbers with $12\leqslant x\leqslant y$ and $p$ denotes a prime. Then
$$\sum_{x<p\leqslant y}\frac{1}{p^2}\leqslant\frac{2.22}{\lfloor x\rfloor\log\lfloor x\rfloor}-\frac{1.61}{\lfloor y\rfloor\log\lfloor y\rfloor}.$$

For an elementary proof using forward differences (and avoiding Riemann-Stieltjes integrals) see Lemma 6 of the preprint [arXiv:1911.12613](https://arXiv:1911.12613). A lower bound with a similar form (but with different constants) can be obtained using the same methods.
As the lower bound for $x$ increases from 12, the constant 2.22 decreases to 1 as predicted by Greg Martin's answer. (For our application we needed explicit constants for an upper bound.)